# Creating functions over Enumerations

Tags: haskell, algebraic-data-types

I just started learning Haskell. I think I've got the basics down, but I want to make sure I'm actually forcing myself to think functionally too.

```
data Dir = Right | Left | Front | Back | Up | Down deriving (Show, Eq, Enum)
inv Right = Left
inv Front = Back
inv Up = Down
```

Anyway, the jist of what I'm trying to do is to create a function to map between each "Dir" and its opposite/inv. I know I could easily continue this for another 3 lines, but I can't help but wonder if there's a better way. I tried adding:

```
inv a = b where inv b = a
```

but apparently you can't do that. So my question is: Is there either a way to generate the rest of the inverses or an altogether better way to create this function?

Thanks much.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If the pairing between `Up` and `Down` and so on is an important feature then maybe this knowledge should be reflected in the type.

```
data Axis = UpDown | LeftRight | FrontBack
data Sign = Positive | Negative
data Dir = Dir Axis Sign
```

`inv` is now easy.

Comment: That's better. Accurately capture the core concept (dimension and direction) in types.

Comment: Makes sense. Finding the inverse of "inv Positive" over "Sign" is better than finding the inverse of "inv Right" over all of "Dir". So the only way to do an 'inverse' cleanly is to make what you're inverting really small...

Comment: @rcb451, you're missing the point.  The fact that `Sign` has fewer data constructors is incidental (though certainly beneficial).  The key observation is that the close relationship between `Left` and `Right` should be reflected in their types, likewise the distant relationship between (for example) `Left` and `Top`.  The type system is there to help with invariants: with more types you can express more precise invariants.

Answer (score 2):

Do you have a closed-form solution over the indices that corresponds to this function? If so, yes, you can use the `Enum` deriving to simplify things. For example,

```
import Prelude hiding (Either(..))

data Dir = Right
         | Front
         | Up

         | Left
         | Back
         | Down
     deriving (Show, Eq, Ord, Enum)

inv :: Dir -> Dir
inv x = toEnum ((3 + fromEnum x) `mod` 6)
```

Note, this *relies on the ordering of the constructors*!

```
*Main> inv Left
Right
*Main> inv Right
Left
*Main> inv Back
Front
*Main> inv Up
Down
```

This is very C-like, exploits the ordering of constructors, and is un-Haskelly. A compromise is to *use more types*, to define a mapping between the constructors and their mirrors, avoiding the use of arithmetic.

```
import Prelude hiding (Either(..))

data Dir = A NormalDir
         | B MirrorDir
     deriving Show

data NormalDir = Right | Front | Up
     deriving (Show, Eq, Ord, Enum)

data MirrorDir = Left  | Back  | Down     
     deriving (Show, Eq, Ord, Enum)

inv :: Dir -> Dir
inv (A n) = B (toEnum (fromEnum n))
inv (B n) = A (toEnum (fromEnum n))
```

E.g.

```
*Main> inv (A Right)
B Left
*Main> inv (B Down)
A Up
```

So at least we didn't have to do arithmetic. And the types distinguish the mirror cases. However, this is very un-Haskelly. It is absolute fine to enumerate the cases! Others will have to read your code at some point...

Answer (score 2):

```
pairs = ps ++ map swap ps where
   ps = [(Right, Left), (Front, Back), (Up, Down)]
   swap (a, b) = (b, a)

inv a = fromJust $ lookup a pairs
```

**[Edit]**

Or how about this?

```
inv a = head $ delete a $ head $ dropWhile (a `notElem`)
        [[Right,Left],[Front,Back],[Up,Down]]
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think I'd recommend this, but the simple answer in my mind would be to add this:

```
inv x = fromJust $ find ((==x) . inv) [Right, Front, Up]
```

---

I couldn't resist tweaking Landei's answer to fit my style; here's a similar and slightly-more-recommended solution that doesn't need the other definitions:

```
inv a = fromJust $ do pair <- find (a `elem`) invList
                      find (/= a) pair
  where invList = [[Right, Left], [Up, Down], [Front, Back]]
```

It uses the Maybe monad.

Comment: Hm? Bug? That is not better than stating `inv x=inv x`.

Comment: I mean add this after the definitions he already wrote for `inv Right`, `inv Front`, `inv Up`. [See for yourself that it works](https://ideone.com/Uc9Px).

Answer (score 1):

It is good to know, that `Enum`eration starts with zero.

Mnemonic: `fmap fromEnum [False,True] == [0,1]`

---

```
import Data.Bits(xor)

-- Enum:       0   1          2   3       4   5
data Dir = Right | Left | Front | Back | Up | Down
           deriving (Read,Show,Eq,Ord,Enum,Bounded)

inv :: Dir -> Dir
inv = toEnum . xor 1 . fromEnum
```